# Spinner и новые данные

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Есть 3 спиннера: каждый из них получает список из базы данных последовательно, т.е. сначала заполняется первый, затем можно выбрать пункт из списка, в зависимости от выбора заполняется второй спиннер и далее. Но при всех 3х заполненных спиннерах можно наблюдать такую картину - при выборе нового пункта в первом должны очищаться 2 и 3 спиннер соответственно, в итоге эти спиннеры оказываются пустыми и при повторном выборе их текст смещается на половину спиннера ниже. Я думаю это все из-за того, что я их очищаю, а потом заполняю новыми данными. Из-за этого высота спиннера изменяется, как это возможно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="developervision.ru.novgu.ChooseSpecialtyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_choose_specialty">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUniversity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Выберите университет:"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerUniversity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textUniversity"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSpecialty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Выберите специальность:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerUniversity"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerSpecialty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textSpecialty"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCourse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Выберите курс:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerSpecialty"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerCourse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textCourse"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Сохранить"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="clickButtonSave"/>

</RelativeLayout>


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerUniversity.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerUniversity.setSelection(university);
    spinnerUniversity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            university = position;

            specialty = UNITIALIZED_PREFERENCES;
            course = UNITIALIZED_PREFERENCES;

            spinnerSpecialty.setAdapter(null);
            spinnerCourse.setAdapter(null);

            initSpinnerSpecialty(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

        spinnerSpecialty.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerSpecialty.setSelection(specialty);
        spinnerSpecialty.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                specialty = position;

                course = UNITIALIZED_PREFERENCES;

                spinnerCourse.setAdapter(null);

                initSpinnerCourse(adapterId.get(specialty));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Нам нужны ваша разметка и минимум кода, в коем вы назначаете данные в спинеры